# Where can I find the current Facebook newsfeed ad dimensions for designing ads for feed only?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design

This is the type of ad I am trying to recreate for a design competition. We will not be using Facebook at all during the process, but I need the proper dimensions to build the graphic. They also want me to include the white boxes above and below the image. Does anyone know the exact dimensions I should be working with?

[image]

Comment: you should probably check facebook guidelines for creating ads, on facebook's website, so I'd say this question is off-topic here

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has detailed specs of all of their supported ad formats available on their site. [You can find them here.](https://www.facebook.com/business/ads-guide)

*Note:* The example in your original post appears to be outdated. Check out the newest [Image Ad Specs for Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/business/ads-guide/image) if you'd like to be as accurate as possible in your recreation of the ad above.